# Converting AngularJS to Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm fairly new to Angular and have no experience with AngularJS; however I found this codepen that I want to duplicate: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpZBBQ?editors=0010

Ive fixed the ng-class and ng-click directives in the template but I am stuck on the js; I've never seen a controller, `$scope`, or `$timeout` in an Angular 6 app so I'm not sure what to do with that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

It's not the same framework, don't be fooled by the similar name.

So, no, you can't duplicate that.

You can setup a project with angular-cli very quickly, and just build your components around that concept.
I'm sure you'll understand it a lot better by building it than by copying.

Comment: Although I agree, they technically have this https://update.angular.io/

Comment: @OvidiuDolha but the lowest version you can choose is 2.0

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: @TimMartens, Yeah with ngUpgrade it's possible but I didn't see the point in including it in my answer.